# Peut-on utiliser le verbe « commander » pour signifier « justifier, se permettre » ?

Tags: sens

Peut-on faire ce qui est mis en question dans le titre ci-dessus, c'est-à-dire, peut-on utiliser le verbe tel que dans la phrase suivante ?

> L'entreprise mise sur son renom pour commander des prix si supérieurs à ceux de ses concurrents.

Answer (score 2):

Non, il n'y a aucun sens de « commander » qui puisse donner une signification claire à cette phrase. Il y aurait le sens de « régir, régler, déterminer, … », on peut dire  qu'une entreprise *détermine* ses prix, mais « commander » semble assez peu idiomatique. S'il était question d'un mécanisme économique qui rende l'entreprise responsable pour la fixation des prix dans l'industrie dont elle fait partie, alors cet usage deviendrait possible.

- Dans ce domaine d'activité l'entreprise X commande les prix depuis déjà longtemps.

Answer (score 0):

Oui c'est possible à mon avis. Je comprends ce sens de [*commander*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C3091) comme *imposer, exiger*. Peut-être que c'est moins usité que *justifier* dans ce genre de tournure. Dans l'exemple en question ou dans quelques autres ([1](https://books.google.com/books?id=SfCdDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA117&ots=msjfPq0tJI&dq=%22commander%20des%20prix%22&pg=PA117#v=onepage&q=%22commander%20des%20prix%22&f=false), [2](https://www.ledevoir.com/opinion/chroniques/374448/le-prix-de-l-histoire)), c'est la position de supériorité ou de notoriété du produit ou de l'entreprise qui donne ainsi l'autorité d'imposer ou d'exiger un prix fort et je trouve donc l'emploi bien relié à la sémantique de ce verbe.